# Normalise table-DynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

In our project we have a vendor table, and skill table(DynamoDB). A vendor can have multiple skills stored as a list of skill Ids, for each vendor. Now I need to get list of vendors having specific skills in the table. I know that we cannot index list property in dynamodb and I have no idea how to noramalise the table so that I can efficiently get the vendor list( i dont want to use elastic search or that kind of things).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to normalize with DynamoDB. You should do the opposite and denormalize. What you could do is create another table `vendor_skills` and have it be keyed by `(skillId, vendorId)` and query that by `skillId` to find all vendors with that skill